# How to check the user status in database first after making changes changes in crud

Tags: php

How do I make every user to check their user_status to get status code 200 every http request?
I have crud with disable account function but the problem is in the user end if i make changes in admin end, and disable user account they still logged in

here is my disable function in my crud:

```
if($_POST["action"] == 'change_status')
{
    $status = '';
    if($_POST['user_status'] == 'Active')
    {
        $status = 'Inactive';
    }
    else
    {
        $status = 'Active';
    }
    $query = '
    UPDATE users SET user_status = :user_status WHERE id = :id
    ';
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':user_status'          => $status,
            ':id'              => $_POST['id']
        )
    );
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    if(isset($result))
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-fill-warning" role="alert">User status set to <strong>'.$status.'</strong><div>';
    }
}
```

and also in every page i have this is my code:

```
if($_SESSION['user_status'] == 'Inactive'){
header("HTTP/1.1 401");
readfile('../../error/401.html');
exit();
}
```

After disabling their account their status is still 'Active' it will make changes if they logout

Answer (score 0):

if status column  type is boolen you can do basicly

Tinyint type for mysql support true and false

```
    $query = '
    UPDATE users SET user_status = !user_status WHERE id = :id
    ';
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(

            ':id'              => $_POST['id']
        )
    );
```

Comment: still not updating the user_status if i the session is already started

Comment: it does not make effect if user still logged in

Comment: how to do make it effect to user side if they already logged in

Comment: What is the logged in mean is has session ?

Comment: UPDATE users SET user_status = !user_status WHERE id = $_SESSION['USER_ID']

Answer (score 0):

Do not save the `user_status` in the `$_SESSION`. Instead check the current status of the user in the database. That way you know if the user is still allowed to use your service/API and not if the user was allowed to use your service/API at the time the session was started (or to be more precise, when the `$_SESSION['user_status']` value was set).